# Symfony 6.4 - Unable to submit form with new line (\n) in textarea after update

Tags: forms, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-503, symfony6

I have updated to symfony 6.4 and suddenly I can't save any form with a textarea that has a new line or any html code like `<p>`. When I write a single line that doesn't wrap, the form submits successfully.

I'm getting a 403 forbidden error

[image: as you see here]

Sometimes when I submit a form without using ajax (with render and form) I get 503 error when submitting a form for the second time, and I have to delete cache in order to submit successfully.

However, for 403 error, I can't do anything to submit it with a new line or any html code.

Here's one example of the code that causes 403:

```
#[Route(path: '/ajax/save/new', name: 'new_lesson_plan')]
public function newLessonPlan(
    LessonPlanRepository $lessonPlanRepo,
    Request $request,
    SessionRepository $sessionRepo,
    Mailer $mailer,
    SendSms $sendSms,
    ShortenUrl $shortenUrl,
    Environment $twig
): Response {
    $new_stuff = $request->request->get('new_stuff');
    $finger_exercises = $request->request->get('finger_exercises');
    $previous_pieces = $request->request->get('previous_pieces');
    $current_piece = $request->request->get('current_piece');
    $techniques_reinforced = $request->request->get('techniques_reinforced');
    $extend_to_learn = $request->request->get('extend_to_learn');
    $print_out = $request->request->get('print_out');
    $assignment_for_student = $request->request->get('assignment_for_student');
    $modify = $request->request->get('modify');
    $sess_id = $request->request->get('session_id');

    $session = $sessionRepo->findOneById($sess_id);

    $activity_string = "";
    $activity_string .= "<h3>Warm-up</h3>";
    $activity_string .= "<p>" . nl2br($finger_exercises) . "</p>";
    $activity_string .= "<h3>Repertoire</h3>";
    $activity_string .= "<p>" . nl2br($previous_pieces) . "</p>";
    $activity_string .= "<h3>Creative</h3>";
    $activity_string .= "<p> Learn: " . nl2br($new_stuff) . "</p>";
    $activity_string .= "<h3>Current piece: " . $current_piece . "</h3>";
    $activity_string .= "<p> This piece will reinforce the following: ". $techniques_reinforced .". I intend to do " . $extend_to_learn . "</p>";
    $activity_string .= "<h3>Print outs</h3>";
    $activity_string .= "<p>" . $print_out . "</p>";
    $activity_string .= "<h3>Assignment</h3>";
    $activity_string .= "<p>" . nl2br($assignment_for_student) . "</p>";

    if($modify == 'false') {
        $lessonPlan = new LessonPlan();
        $lp = 'Lesson Plan';
    } else {
        $lessonPlan = $lessonPlanRepo->findOneBySession($session);
        $lp = 'Assessed Lesson Plan';
    }


    $lessonPlan->setAddedOn($session->getBeginAt());

    $lessonPlan->setSession($session);
    $lessonPlan->setStudent($session->getStudent());
    $lessonPlan->setAddedOn(new \Datetime());
    $lessonPlan->setWork($new_stuff);
    $lessonPlan->setActivities($activity_string);
    $entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($lessonPlan);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $student = $lessonPlan->getStudent();
    $teacher = $session->getTeacher();
    $html = $twig->render('pdf/student_lesson_plan.html.twig', [
        'session' => $session,
        'lesson_plan' => $lessonPlan,
    ]);

    $uigName = explode("-", (string) $session->getUserInstrumentGrade())[0];

    $urlShort = $shortenUrl...;
    $sendSms->quickSend...;

    $mailer->sendEmailWithAttachment(...);
    $this->addFlash(
        'success',
        'The lesson plan was sent successfully.'
    );

    return new JsonResponse($sess_id);

}
```

I have pasted the whole function because I don't know if any of the lines is causing the issue.

And here's the controller for the form:

```
    #[Route(path: '/new/for/{session_id}', name: 'lesson_plan_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function new(Request $request, SessionRepository $sessionRepo, UserInstrumentGradeRepository $uigRepo, LessonPlanRepository $lessonPlanRepo, $session_id): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED');
    $session = $sessionRepo->findOneById($session_id);

    $lessonPlan = new LessonPlan();
    $uig = $session->getUserInstrumentGrade();
    $sessions = $uig->getSessions();

    $lessonPlan->setAddedOn($session->getBeginAt());

    $form = $this->createForm(LessonPlanType::class, $lessonPlan);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $lessonPlan->setSession($session);
        $lessonPlan->setStudent($session->getStudent());
        $lessonPlan->setAddedOn(new \Datetime());
        $entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($lessonPlan);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('lesson_plan_index', ['student_id' => $lessonPlan->getStudent()->getId()], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    $lessonPlanForThisSession = $lessonPlanRepo->findOneBySession($session);

    return $this->render('lesson_plan/new.html.twig', [
        'session' => $session,
        'sessions' => $sessions,
        'lessonPlanForThisSession' => $lessonPlanForThisSession,
        'lesson_plan' => $lessonPlan,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You should start removing lines to check where this error occurs. Usually, Symfony has a pretty good debugging mode. Also, `$urlShort = $shortenUrl...;` doesn't look valid after all

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried everything on earth, including removing lines and testing before I posted here. I have worked on this for 3 months now, without success. I have placed the dots to show that there's more code there that's not shown.

Comment: What **exactly** did you try? Even with `die()` in your code, you could check how far the execution works fine

Comment: I get what you're saying, and I appreciate. This seems like a beginner question, I know. That's why I've taken too long to ask. I've coded with symfony for over 8 years and I've used php for over 10 years. I know what you're saying, and I've tried everything.

Comment: I'm talking about a form that saves successfully, but with a new line in any textarea, it gives a 403. Every kind of test gives that behavior

Answer (score 0):

It happens that mod_security was activated by my hosting company.

According to [this information on namecheap.com](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9542/22/what-is-modsecurity-and-why-do-we-need-it/), the most common error triggered by a mod_security rule on our shared servers is 403 Forbidden one... Sometimes, due to poor website coding, mod_security may incorrectly determine that a certain request is malicious, while it is actually legitimate. When it happens, you still get a 403 error.

Having them deactivate the mod_security enabled me to submit the forms successfully.

I still don't know where I'm doing the "poor website coding" but this is the reason for the error.